# Unable to Output Embedded Ruby code in Ruby on Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm having a very small problem with my Rails App. I'm setting up a Mac OS X for Ruby on Rails development and testing purposes.

But for some reasons, my Views are not being rendered properly. I'm able to output all the HTML content in my views, but when i use any Ruby/Rails code such as:

```
  <% 'Hello World' %> or 
  <%- 'Hello World!' %>
```

It is not being outputted at all... Please help.. I get no errors - nothing.

My environment is:

```
 Ruby: 1.9.2
 Rails 3.0.3
 OS: Mac OS X
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= 'Hello World!' %>
```

its beacause  without `=` your code is only processed. `-` is used e.g.

```
<%- if true %>
  <%= "Hello" %>
```

that will display only `Hello`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `=` sign:

```
<%= 'Hello World!' %>
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot, i was trying the `-` symbol.. :)